# find all possible solution without repetition in 3 arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have 3 arrays and I need to get the sum of these 3 arrays. Here are my arrays
[37,9,7]
[42,50,2]
[57,92,52]
I need to find all the possible solution without any repetition.
In this case, I need to find 6 solutions which are,
37+50+52, 9+2+57, 7+50+57, 9+42+52, 37+92+2, 7+42+92

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[3] = { 37, 9, 7 };
    int arr1[3] = { 42, 50, 2 };
    int arr2[3] = { 57, 92, 52 };
    int arr3[3] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                if (i != j && i!= k && j !=k)
                    arr3[i] = arr[i] + arr1[j] + arr2[k];
            }

    cout << "The sum is " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << arr3[i] << " " << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The outcome only has first 3 solution correct and the rest are wrong.
My outcome:

```
The sum is
131
68
114
-858993460
-858993460
57
```

Comment: Since you don't want repetitions, you can think about looping over all permutations instead of `N` loops over arrays of dimensions `N`. You will then reduce a bit the complexity from `N^N` to `N!`.

Comment: Does that mean I should create another function and put all permutations into an array and the loop over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Luchian's answer is correct and to the point. You should however try learning modern C++, even if you are a beginner. Unfortunately most teachers/instructors leave it as an "Advanced topic", and it shouldn't be as that. Writing modern C++ means (most of the time) making good use of the Standard Library. Most of the time your code will be much safer. This is how I'd do it using containers and algorithms from the Standard Library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::size_t N = 3; // number of arrays
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arrays;

    arrays.push_back({ 37, 9, 7 }); // first array
    arrays.push_back({ 42, 50, 2 }); // second array
    arrays.push_back({ 57, 92, 52 }); // third array

    std::vector<int> result; // here we store the results

    std::vector<std::size_t> perm(N);
    // fill in the vector with 0 ... N-1, which we'll later permute
    std::iota(perm.begin(), perm.end(), 0); 
    do { // loop over all permutations
        int sum = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < perm.size(); ++i)
            sum += arrays[i][perm[i]];
        result.push_back(sum);
    } while (std::next_permutation(perm.begin(), perm.end()));

    // display the result
    std::cout << "The possible sums are: " << std::endl;
    for(auto elem: result)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
}
```

This solution decreases the complexity from `N^N` to `N!`, and it is also scalable.

**EDIT**

As @Bathsheba mentioned in the comment below, if you want to be super duper safe, then you should guard agains overflowing the `int` in the loop. There are various ways of doing this, such as using an `unsigned int` if you know your elements are positive. `unsigned` types never overflow, they wrap around the maximum value, so, in the worst case, you end up "reseting" your sum.

Comment: A great solution (plus one) although you could guard against undefined behaviour of `int` overflow by using an `unsigned`. Then it would be truly safe.

Comment: Thanks.  Would you mind explain the line `for (auto elem : result)` ?

Comment: @Chow this is the new range-based `for` introduced C++11 and later. It kinda "replicates" the Python for-range loops. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for more details. `auto` just tells the compiler to deduce the type, so instead of using `int elem: result`, you can use `auto elem: result`, or `const auto& elem: result` to pass by reference (not the case here since fundamental types are best passed by value).

Comment: @Bathsheba indeed, that's true, thanks for the remark. I just used the type OP used. In general, when writing such algorithms, I prefer to template-ize them. Of course, dealing with overflows becomes tricky then, and most of the time I don't really care (unless the problem becomes serious, e.g computing a determinant (where one can easily over/uder-flow) or stuff like that).

Answer (score 4):

`int arr3[3] = {};` is meant to hold all solutions, but only has 3 elements. You're only setting these 3 elements.

Maybe you should increase the size to the number of solutions you expect and keep a separate counter for `arr3` - since `i` will only go from 0 to 2.

The actual code is left as an exercise.